# Python - Web scraping pages using Comet and HTTP streaming

Tags: python, streaming, comet

I have to extract the data from [fxstreet](http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/)
I extracted the HTML code with firebug and it seems like the webpage is using Comet and HTTP streaming.

I would like to fill in a dictionary every second with the data without having to refresh the page. I did it with urllib.urlopen but I am obliged to do a query every second.

Someone knows a proper way to pull the data from the Comet & http streaming?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) to write an asynchronous HTTP client to consume your service. There have been quite a few projects built for working with the Twitter Streaming API that you might look to for inspiration:

- https://github.com/fiorix/twisted-twitter-stream - `twisted`
- https://github.com/dustin/twitty-twister - `twisted`
- https://github.com/atl/twitstream - `asyncore`,  `pycurl` or `tornado`
- https://github.com/godavemon/TwitTornado - `tornado`
- https://github.com/thruflo/close.consumer - `gevent`

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in this matter, but what I know is that Comet works in a way that **responds request only when the time is near the limit or there was some change on the server**. Thus you can make Comet requests and **assume that nothing changed unless the Comet request has returned something**.

So, basically, you can make Comet requests and **store the data returned by Comet request in the table**. By the other request (which can be sent every second), **check the table for newly added data** and return it if found.

Is this what you expected?

Comment: thanks you both but It is not exactly what I expected, I **don't want to send a request every second to get the data**..

I want to be permanently "connected" to the data stream and fill automatically my dictionnary with the new data. without requesting or refreshing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the data and instantiate the query again in the same instant, not in 1 second - Comet just means the server won't respond until it has new data available.